# On an inequality concerning the strict cohomological dimension of a profinite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, profinite-groups

This is an exercise from Serre’s book on Galois cohomology.

Let $G$ be a profinite group and $H$ a normal closed subgroup and suppose that the cohomological dimension at the prime $p$ of $G/H$ is non-zero. If $cd_p,scd_p$ stand for the cohomological dimension at $p$ (resp. the strict cohomological dimension at $p$), it is claimed that
$$scd_p G \leq scd_p G/H +cd_p H.$$

Is this true? I tried applying the LHS spectral sequence, and see that for this inequality to hold, if we let $n=scd_p G/H, m= cd_p H,$ it is enough to show that $H^n(G/H,H^{m+1}(H,A))$ is zero for all discrete $G$-modules $A.$ But why does this hold?

**Update**
I should clarify that if we instead add the requirement that if the claim instead would be that $$scd_p G \leq cd_p G/H + scd_p H$$ when $cd_p H \neq 0,$ then this is straightforward to show, using the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence. But this is not what Serre asks... Of course, it is possible that there is a mistake, but then I would be very interested in a counterexample to the inequality!

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but in this section Serre proves that $scd_p(K)$ is equal to $cd_p(K)$ or $cd_p(K)+1$, and that $cd_p(G)\le cd_p(H)+cd_p(G/H)$. Therefore if there is a counterexample to the given formula, we simultaneously have $scd_p(G)=cd_p(G)+1$, $scd_p(G/H)=cd_p(G/H)$ and $cd_p(G)=cd_p(G/H)+cd_p(H)$.

Comment: @Ycor Thanks for the comment! I did not manage to produce a counterexample unfortunately. Another observation is that Serre shows that if the strict cohomological dimension of $G$ is $cd_p G +1,$ then there is an open subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $H^{cd_p G+1}(K,\mathbb{Z})(p) \neq 0.$ Maybe one can use this somehow, if the statement holds? I do not see how though.

Comment: @Ycor Sorry for asking, but do you believe the statement of the problem to be true? My thought was first that maybe the statement should be that if the p-coh. dimension of H is nonzero, then $scd_p G \leq cd_p G/H +scd_p H.$ This is true and not too hard to show, but I can not find counterexamples to the original formulation.

Comment: I don't have an expectation based on mathematical grounds, but an error in a book or article by J-P. Serre is highly unlikely.

Comment: You might enjoy knowing that @YCor dubbed this an "exercise … of research level" [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293308/trace-class-operator-satisfies-sum-lambda-n-infty#comment727931_293308).  (I can't figure out how to write that without looking like I'm being sarcastic.  I mean it totally sincerely.  It would make me feel good to know!)

Comment: @LSpice I meant "research-level" in the sense of MathOverflow's standards (since questions are often closed on the grounds of not being research level, and of being "exercise-level"). Anyway this was of little and mainly chatting in the context where I write this comment, and this is of no interest as a comment of this very question, unless I should justify why I didn't vote to close it; thanks for echoing anyway. (PS I've erased the link from my comment on the other post, because the site automatically displays the link on the right margin, while the questions are unrelated)

Comment: Check Theorem 13 (Tower Theorem) on Stephen Shatz's "Profinite Groups, Arithmetic and Geometry", page 61. Seems more general then Serre's formulation, and I think his isomorphism may solve it... but he gets away with spectral sequences though!

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza Would you mind elaborating why you think the stated isomorphism will solve the problem?

Comment: @Dedalus it was a rushed commentary... Actually all those statements from Shatz's book are in Serre's, although scattered in a different order. But he elaborates a bit more on his proofs, I'm reading them now to see if I get any ideas. Anyway, there is a group currenctly attacking this exercise during this week. If we make any concrete progress I'll post it here as a comment or an answer.

Comment: @HenriqueAugustoSouza If I can make a suggestion, I would think that it would be worthwhile to look for counterexamples. It is possible that there is a typo in the exercise.