# Trace-class operator satisfies $\sum |\lambda_n|<\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, traces

Here's an "exercise" which I thought should be easy, but which I find myself unable to do.

Let $V$ be a Banach space.

Recall that an operator $f:V\to V$ is **trace-class** if it is in the image of the natural map $V\otimes_\pi V'\to \mathcal L(V,V)$, where $\otimes_\pi$ denotes the projective tensor product, and $V'=\mathcal L(V,\mathbb C)$ is the continuous dual of $V$.

> *Exercise:*  **[Edit: this is probably *FALSE*; thank you *Mateusz Wasilewski*]**
>   Let $f:V\to V$ be a trace-class linear map which is "diagonalizable", in the sense that the linear span of its eigenspaces is dense in $V$.
>   Write $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ for the eigenvalues of $f$ (enumerated with multiplicities). Then $$\sum |\lambda_n|<\infty.$$

Given that my previous "exercise" turned out to be probably false, here's a new one:

> *Exercise v2:* 
>   Let $f:V\to V$ be a trace-class linear map which is diagonalizable (in the same sense as above), and whose eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ are all positive real numbers. Then $$\sum \lambda_n<\infty.$$

Can someone please help me prove it?
And if this second exercise also too difficult, here's an even simpler one (which I also don't know how to prove):

> *Exercise v3:* 
>   Let $f:V\to V$ be a trace-class linear map which is diagonalizable (in the same sense as above), with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda_n=0.$$

PS: I'm also interested in the same question when $V$ is Frechet, or when $V$ is a general complete locally convex topological vector space.

Comment: What makes you believe that the statement holds true?

Comment: This happens only for Hilbert spaces, see Eigenvalues of p-summing and I_p-type operators in Banach spaces by Johnson, König, Maurey and Retherford, Journal of Functional Analysis, vol. 32 (1979), 353-380.

Comment: @Mateusz Wasilewski. Thank you. I have edited my question.

Comment: We proved that if every nuclear (what you call trace class are more usually called nuclear) operator on $X$ has absolutely summable eigenvalues, then $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. It is not clear to me that one can get a nuclear operator s.t. the eigenvectors have dense span. If you just want an example, it is natural to restrict the operator to the closed span $Y$ of the eigenvectors, but there is no reason that the resulting operator on $Y$ will be nuclear.

Comment: You have an exotic use of the word "exercise"...

Comment: @YCor. At first, I really thought that my question was exercise-level, and that I just needed some help. Then the word "exercise" remained. (To my defence, I did use quotes around the word "exercise".)

Comment: I don't think "exercise-level" has much meaning. In Bourbaki or in Serre's books there are exercises of research level (at least the sense which makes it appropriate for this site). "Exercise" doesn't refer to the level, but rather to the origin of the problem

Comment: Anyway, I was moaning about the use of "exercise" because I found it confusing: it can deter people from looking for a counterexample, thinking you know for some reason that the statement holds true. If you don't know whether a statement is true, "exercise" is not the right wording. If you're afraid that it might be "too easy", there are plenty of other ways to formulate it.

Comment: Nuclear operators are $2$-absolutely summing and hence the eigenvalues are square summable.

Comment: Maybe, $s$-numbers or singular values can help here. A good source for them and their use in operator ideals is the book: MR0582655  Reviewed Pietsch, Albrecht Operator ideals. Translated from German by the author. North-Holland Mathematical Library, 20. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam-New York, 1980. 451 pp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, exercise 3 has a positive answer: Nuclear operators are absolutely $2$-summing, and $2$-summing operators have $2$-summable eigenvalues (see, e.g., Tomczak's book).

Exercise 2 has a negative answer, but I am not satisfied with the example and do not know what happens in various classical spaces.  First, note that it is sufficient to find for each $n$ a space $X_n$ on which there is a rank $n$ projection $P_n$ that has nuclear norm of order $n^{1/2}$. One can on $(I-P_n)X_n$ construct a diagonalizable (in the sense of the OP) operator $U_n$ with positive eigenvalues and nuclear norm as small as desired, so $S_n :=P_n + U_n(I-P_n)$ will have nuclear norm of order $n^{1/2}$ but the eigenvalues sum to about $n$. Multiply  the $S_n$ by suitable constants and take an $\ell_2$ direct sum to see that exercise 2 has a negative answer.

The problem is that on a space that has the approximation property, the nuclear norm dominates the trace for finite rank operators, so the desired $X_n$ must fail the approximation property.  Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on one's point of view) Pisier constructed a space on which the nuclear norm of every finite rank operator is of order the norm of the operator.  Now use the fact that in every Banach space there is a projection of norm at most $n^{1/2}$ onto every $n$ dimensional subspace (also in Tomczak's book).

Comment: Is this the space in the Acta paper?

Comment: Yes, Yemon.  Pisier, Gilles
Counterexamples to a conjecture of Grothendieck. 
Acta Math. 151 (1983), no. 3-4, 181–208.